# dotnet crash using POSForDotNet.SDK

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write a dotnet forms project that uses POS scanners. I am trying to use the POSForDotNet.SDK v1.14.1. I included it with NuGet and can build the app fine, however I see a warning in visual studio:

```
Package 'POSForDotNet.SDK 1.14.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

When I run the project I get an immediate crash on this line `explorer = new PosExplorer(this);`

The crash is:

```
Inner Exception
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.AppDomainSetup.set_ApplicationBase(System.String)'.
```

Not sure if its related to the warning above or not - Does anyone know how to go about fixing these issues? First time using dotnet so not sure if theres something obvious im missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target framework for your project is `.NET Core 3.1` but `POSForDotNet.SDK v1.14.1` does not support `.NET Core 3.1`.

Only fix is to change target framework of your project to `.NET Framework` instead of `.NET Core`.